# Retrieve first 100 rows sorted by a function without evaluating all rows in the table?

Tags: database, sorting, similarity

I think the question in the title speaks it all and is general.

I can give a concrete example as well:

I have tagged articles and want to find `similar` articles with the tags associated with them.
The score function will look at two articles and count the number of tags in common.

Since the score is not stored anywhere, I'll have to calculate the score everytime I need to find similar articles given an article.
`But this is too expensive.`

> 1. What is the common work-around to this kind of problem in general?
> 2. Is there a better approach for my specific `tag` problem? (e.g. [solr's moreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis))

*edit*
I'm using postgres, if that matters.
I'm looking for a general solution that people used successfully, such as `you should batch calculate the score and save it somewhere` and etc...

Comment: If it's expensive to compute and you need to compute it often, batch process and cache. (Consider incremental updates too, with every so often recalculations to confirm accuracy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The answer will vary *wildly* by database product and version. For example, in some database products, it may be the case that a view or an indexed view might be faster than the more common solution...
2. Typically the way to handle a situation like this is by precalculating the result. You can do that in a handful of ways:

   a. You can use something like triggers (added in the SQL 99 standard) that update the counts as rows are added, updated or removed from the source table. In this solution, you are making a (presumably) small sacrifice on inserts, updates and deletes of the source table in order to make significant gains in retrieving the information.

   b. You can use a data warehouse where you accept some level of latency of live data to reported data. That means you accept that the data queried from the data warehouse will be stale by some accepted number of minutes, hours, days, or weeks. The data warehouse works by periodically querying the live OLTP (Online Transaction Processing) data and updates the OLAP (Online Analytical Processing) database which contains the precalculated results. You then run your reports off the OLAP data or a combination of OLTP and OLAP data. A formal database warehouse isn't required to achieve the equivalent results. You could write a procedure which is executed on a timer that updates a table periodically with updated results.